# XML Get a specific element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an XML doc that looks like this:

```
<root type="object">
  <totalResults type="number">x</totalResults>
  <itemsPerPage type="number">x</itemsPerPage>
  <startIndex type="number">x</startIndex>
  <schemas type="array">
    <item type="string">x</item>
  </schemas>
  <Resources type="array">
    <item type="object">
      <schemas type="array">
        <item type="string">x</item>
      </schemas>
      <id type="string">x</id>
      <externalId type="null"></externalId>
      <meta type="object">
        <created type="string">x</created>
        <location type="string">x</location>
      </meta>
      <userName type="string">x</userName>
      <emails type="array">
        <item type="object">
          <value type="string">x.x@x.com</value>
          <primary type="boolean">x</primary>
        </item>
      </emails>
    </item>
  </Resources>
</root>
```

And I am trying to get the email address like this:

```
 var emails = xmlContent.Root.Elements("Resources").Elements("item").Elements("Emails");
            foreach (XElement elem in emails)
            {
                Console.Write(elem.Value);
            }
```

This does not work.  Any thoughts on how I can get the email addresses from this type of XML XDocument in C#?  I've looked around at a few forums and tutorials but I cannot seem to get a handle on XPaths, etc.

Comment: Emails is not the same as emails at least

Comment: You also need well-formed xml. The Resources tag isn't closed.

Comment: @PalleDue - Thanks for catching that too it was just an error when I was editing the content of the XML to post online.  I had values in there I couldn't share with the world.  Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var emails = xmlContent.Root.Elements("Resources").Elements("item").Elements("emails");
        foreach (XElement elem in emails)
        {
            Console.Write(elem.Value);
        }
```

That works. You had a spelling error. XML is case sensitive

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Thanks for catching that for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader("<root ...")); //// load xml file
 var emails = xdoc.Descendants("Resources").Descendants("emails").ToList(); //// select all emails
```

I'm using `Descendants` because it finds children at any level and it searches entire subtree but `Elements` only finds immediate children